# angular 2 input ok but property is undefined

Tags: angular

I've been searching for questions already posted but none seem to answer this particular case.

Basically, I have a parent component which passes data to the child component. Nothing unusual in the html:

```
<child-component [dataChild]="dataParent"></child-component>
```

`dataParent` is the result of an http call and it is initialised with a subscriber:

```
this.myService.myObserver.subscribe(d => {
      this.dataParent = d;          
});
```

`dataParent` will now be something like this:

```
{
 name: "some random name",
 id: 1
}
```

In the child html this won't throw an error and the object above will be displayed as expected:

```
<p>{{dataChild | json}}</p>
```

However, this will:

```
<p>{{dataChild.name}}</p>
```

I've seen in other answers that the way some people are dealing with async properties is by using *ngIf. However, I think that's a bit hacky and the problem here is that the error happens only when a property is being accessed.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: did you try the async pipe ?

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `*ngIf` as you said in comment you can achive this using elvis operator only,  The purpose of the Elvis operator is to allow us to specify bindings where the bound data will become available at a later time. and here in your case also same happened your data is available to component before the binding. so here we use elevis operator only to restrict from throwing error ans when data is availabel to component it is automatically bind to component.
so you can use

```
<p>{{dataChild?.name}}</p>
```

for more explanation see here i have created one dummt plunker assuming your use case hope this clears everything.

<kbd>[Working Example Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8wBnEHOS5zNGXNhg9Tzy?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Elvis operator like this:

```
<p>{{dataChild?.name}}</p>
```

Comment: Uhm interesting. The error is gone, but now interpolation is not working as <p> is empty and nothing gets displayed (same as if no value had been passed to the @Input)